# Draw in the nonclient area with Direct2D

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi, direct2d

On this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-ncpaint it is explained how to draw in the nonclient area with GDI.

How can I draw in the nonclient area of my window with Direct2D without having to deal with GDI or GDI+ ?

Comment: Have you tried HDC-based target?

Comment: See [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe).

Comment: Thanks you but I don't understand how can I draw in the frame like Firefox or Microsoft Office do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `WM_NCPAINT` is old. Using it will disable the DWM theme-ing for the window, giving a windows classic/7 basic look. So don't do it.

But to use any rendering API do draw in the client area, remove the standard window frame from the window by returning 0 when wParam is true in your `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message.

```
case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
    if (static_cast<bool>(wParam))
           return 0;
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

If you want to keep the standard borders, recalculate the window bounds in `WM_NCCALCSIZE`.

Then to get a "client area" title bar, use `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` and extend it from the `TOP`.

Make sure to handle `WM_NCHITTEST` so that dragging your window will work too.

Make sure to premultiply your `ALPHA` in direct2d.
Drawing a rectangle at (0,0) will draw a rectangle in the titlebar of your new custom window.

**SEE: https://github.com/oberth/custom-chrome**